# whtsapp bot from twilio and nodejs - Wait for Reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Trying to create a WhatsApp bot through twilio
Can send one sided messages
Unable to send a response message on a completed question
Sending sample code that doesn't work
From what it seems the reference to POST is not the correct reference
Thank you

```js
app.post('/message', (req, res) => {
  const message = req.body.Body;
  
  if (message === 'hello') {
    client.messages
      .create({
        body: 'Hello, how can I help you?',
        from: 'YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER',
        to: 'USER_PHONE_NUMBER'
      })
      .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain more?! Why do you not use Twilio Studio to build a chatbot?! Did your Incoming Message Webhook configure with the endpoint that you created?

Comment: Can't figure out how I form a message sent to the customer to reply to it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `client.messages.create()` if you "just" want to reply to an incoming message. This is possible but isn't recommended as the webhook call might return a error status code even though the reply was successful.
Instead, you can reply with a TwiML response:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { MessagingResponse } = require('twilio').twiml;

const app = express();

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

  res.type('text/xml').send(twiml.toString());
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

PS: Here's the related [doc file for this use-case](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-node-js).

Comment: Is this also for whatsapp?  Should the condition be sms===message?

Comment: Yes, **if** you use the same webhook for incoming whatsapp messages.

Comment: I noticed you also asked about a condition. I'm not sure to which condition you are referring to. The snippet above only uses "sms" as a name for the route which could be any route as long as you enter the right callback URL in the WhatsApp configuration.